# jQuery hover fade p tag out and fade another in

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, fade

So I am having a problem getting this to work. I have 3 modules with id's #mod1, #mod2, #mod3. When you hover over these I want them to fade out the visible P tag and fade in another.

```
<ul id="homeModules">
    <li id="mod1"><a href="/portfolio/">VIEW OUR GALLERY</a></li>
    <li id="mod2"><a href="/about/">MEET SARAH</a></li>
    <li id="mod3"><a href="/become-a-client/">BECOME A CLIENT</a></li>
</ul>

<p class="homeTags" id="homeTag1">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet.</p>               
<p class="homeTags" id="homeTag2">The Google Fonts API will.</p>                
<p class="homeTags" id="homeTag3">Check out more advanced techniques.</p>

#homeTag2, #homeTag3 {
    display: none;
}

$('#mod1').hover(function(){
    $('#homeTag2,#homeTag3').fadeOut(250);
    setTimeout(function(){
        $('#homeTag1').fadeIn(250);
    }, 500);
});

$('#mod2').hover(function(){
    $('#homeTag1,#homeTag3').fadeOut(250);
    setTimeout(function(){
        $('#homeTag2').fadeIn(250);
    }, 500);
});

$('#mod3').hover(function(){
    $('#homeTag1,#homeTag2').fadeOut(250);
    setTimeout(function(){
        $('#homeTag3').fadeIn(250);
    }, 500);
});
```

Comment: Is your CSS wrapped in `<style>` tags in your actual code?

Comment: can you describe better what exactly is not working? btw you don't need the timeout. The second parameter of fadeOut is a callback that is called when the fadeout is finished (See http://api.jquery.com/fadeOut/)

Comment: I added the timeout because the 2nd p tag was fading in and bumping up. I wanted to get rid of that. Also, when I move the mouse quickly across the LI elements sometimes I get more than 1 p tag to appear.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You are over-complicating, you can instead try this way:

HTML - Removed ids from li's

```
<ul id="homeModules">
    <li data-target="#homeTag1"><a href="/portfolio/">VIEW OUR GALLERY</a></li>
    <li data-target="#homeTag2"><a href="/about/">MEET SARAH</a></li>
    <li data-target="#homeTag3"><a href="/become-a-client/">BECOME A CLIENT</a></li>
</ul>
```

JS

```
var $homeTags = $('.homeTags');
$homeTags.filter(':first').show(); //Show the first one
$('#homeModules > li').hover(function(){
    var $target = $($(this).data('target')); //Get the target reading from data attribute of the hovered li
    $target.stop(true, true).fadeIn(250, function(){ //fadeIn the target and on completion of this
        $homeTags.filter(':visible').not($target).fadeOut(250); //fadeOut the others
    })
});
```

**[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/mbyqH/)**

You can also do this way as well utilizing the index and (not using any ids or data-targets) for your current html, but the one before is more explicit.

```
$('.homeTags:first').show();
$('#homeModules > li').hover(function(){
    var $target = $('.homeTags').eq($(this).index())
    $target.fadeIn(250, function(){
        $('.homeTags:visible').not($target).fadeOut(250);
    });
});
```

**[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/GEp25/)**

Comment: I want to have the visble p tag fade out completely before  new one is faded in. In your example the 2nd one fades in below the first and then bumps up when the 1st one is faded out. Also, the other problem Im having is that if you run the mouse over them really fast it sometimes shows two P tags.

Comment: @drooh You could just do the reverse of it. FOr the second problem i have updated my first fiddle.

Comment: thanks! that seems to work well. I must say that it seems a bit complex to do something that to me seems like it should be easier.

Comment: @drooh One issue with your implementation is that it is not easily maintainable and extensible, every time you need to add one more section you need to attach a handler to it. (Just imagine what if you have 10 of them) The way i have done you don't need to do it. However i hope my inline explanation help you understand that. If this answered your question to your satisfaction would you mind accepting the answer?

Answer (score 0):

HTML

```
<ul id="homeModules">
  <li id="mod1"><a href="/portfolio/">VIEW OUR GALLERY</a></li>
  <li id="mod2"><a href="/about/">MEET SARAH</a></li>
  <li id="mod3"><a href="/become-a-client/">BECOME A CLIENT</a></li>
</ul>
<div class="homeTags" id="homeTag1">
  <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet.</p>
</div>
<div class="homeTags" id="homeTag2">
  <p>The Google Fonts API will.</p>
</div>
<div class="homeTags" id="homeTag3">
  <p>Check out more advanced techniques.</p>
</div>
```

CSS

```
#homeTag2, #homeTag3 {
    display: none;
}
```

JQUERY

```
$("#homeModules li").on("mouseenter", function () {
  var whichLink = $(this).attr("id").slice(-1);

  if ($("#homeTag" + whichLink).css("display") == "block") {
    return false;
  } else {
    $(".homeTags").hide();
    $("#homeTag" + whichLink).show();
  }
});
```